# Building a polymorphic has_many through nested form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, nested-forms, has-many-through

Okay, so I hate to ask, but I'm soooo stuck on this.

I **had** `Users` who **had** many `Stands` (as in exhibition stands) through `Permissions`.

And so my registrations controller looked like this:

```
def new
  @registree = User.new
  @registree.build_company
  @registree.permissions.build.build_stand
end
```

And my form looked like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @registree, url: register_path do |f| %>
  ... stuff ...
  <%= f.simple_fields_for(:permissions) do |perms| %>
    <%= perms.simple_fields_for(:stands) do |stand| %>
      ... stuff ...
    <% end %>
  <% end %
<% end %>
```

And it worked!

But then the client wanted `Users` to have many `Pavilions` (exhibition term) as well.

So I decided to make my has_many through relationship polymorphic.

So now my Permission model looks like this:

```
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :level, :user_id, :ownable_id, :ownable_type, :ownable_attributes

  belongs_to :ownable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ownable
end
```

And the ownable_type can now be either `Stand` or `Pavilion`.

That works in some simple tests.

Magic.

But I cannot get my head around how to build a nested form for this.

So with my new found polymorphism this line in my Registrations Controller throws an error

```
@registree.permissions.build.build_stand
```

Which kind of makes sense, because there's no direct relation to a stand in my `Permission` model, it's to an `ownable` thing, which can be a stand or pavilion.

So I tried `build_ownable` which doesn't work either.

So then I tried simply bypassing the `Permission` nesting in the form.

With this in the controller

```
@registree.stands.build
```

And this in my `User` model.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :stands
```

That got me as far as displaying and submitting the form, but it never created the stand. So clearly the relationship isn't building properly there.

Can anybody lend a helping hand, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), you'd have to define it like this:

```
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :permissable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end

class Stand < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :permissions, as: :permissable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions
end

class Pavilion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions, as: :permissable
end
```